# Анимация волны (wave) svg по атрибуту d path

Tags: css, css3, html5, svg, анимация

У меня есть [следующий эффект](http://tympanus.net/Development/OffCanvasMenuEffects/wave.html), сделанный с помощью svg анимации.

Код svg + путь анимации из исходников:

Волна идет снизу. Моя задача разместить ее сверху. И вроде все хорошо, с помощью illustrator отразил фигуру по вертикали для изменения отправных точек движения анимации. Однако сам путь движения изменить не могу, так как при загрузке `data-morph-shape` в illustrator, не отражаются точки переходов, а отражается только итог: прямоугольник меню. Подскажите пожалуйста как изменить `path` из расчета изменения положения svg файла?

```html
    <div class="morph-shape" id="morph-shape" data-morph-open="M0,100h1000V0c0,0-136.938,0-224,0C583,0,610.924,0,498,0C387,0,395,0,249,0C118,0,0,0,0,0V100z">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 1000 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
    <path d="M0,100h1000l0,0c0,0-136.938,0-224,0c-193,0-170.235-1.256-278-35C399,34,395,0,249,0C118,0,0,100,0,100L0,100z"/>
    </svg>

</div>
```

Comment: Обычно проблемы решаются путём проб и ошибок, а не исключительно в уме. Вашего кода недостаточно, чтобы попробовать что-то сделать с ним и добиться нужного вам результата.

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/562680/%D0%9F%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0-svg-path-d-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82/563554#563554

Answer (score 1):

just do it :)

```
<path transform="rotate(-180 500,50)" 
  d="M0,100h1000l0,0c0,0-136.938,0-224,0c-193,0-170.235-1.256-278-35C399,34,395,0,249,0C118,0,0,100,0,100L0,100z"
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

- Патч волны лучше нарисовать самому в векторном редакторе, тогда не
  придется ничего подгонять и не придется ломать голову, почему анимация не работает.

```css
* {
padding:0;
margin:0;
}
body {
background:greenyellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="morph-shape" id="morph-shape"  >
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="200%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 1000 300" preserveAspectRatio="none">
<path fill="dodgerblue" d="M0.00,49.98 C149.99,150.00 271.49,-49.98 500.00,49.98 L500.00,0.00 L0.00,0.00 Z"/>
</svg>
</div>
```

- Теперь рисуем финальное положение волны

```css
* {
padding:0;
margin:0;
}
body {
background:greenyellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="morph-shape" id="morph-shape"  >
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="200%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 1000 300" preserveAspectRatio="none">
<path fill="dodgerblue" d="M0.00,49.98 C157.16,-41.94 281.88,148.52 500.00,49.98 L500.00,0.00 L0.00,0.00 Z;"/>
</svg>
</div>
```

- Анимация атрибута `d` патча волны

```css
* {
padding:0;
margin:0;
}
body {
background:greenyellow;
}
</style>
```

```html
<div class="morph-shape" id="morph-shape"  >
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="200%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 1000 300"  preserveAspectRatio="none">
<path fill="dodgerblue" d="M0.00,49.98 C149.99,150.00 271.49,-49.98 500.00,49.98 L500.00,0.00 L0.00,0.00 Z">
  <animate
    attributeName="d"
 dur="7s"
 repeatCount="indefinite" 
  values=" 
    M0.00,49.98 C149.99,150.00 271.49,-49.98 500.00,49.98 L500.00,0.00 L0.00,0.00 Z;
 M0.00,49.98 C157.16,-41.94 281.88,148.52 500.00,49.98 L500.00,0.00 L0.00,0.00 Z;
    M0.00,49.98 C149.99,150.00 271.49,-49.98 500.00,49.98 L500.00,0.00 L0.00,0.00 Z" />
</path> 
</svg> 
</div>
```