# Плавная смена (Анимация) Svg Path D координат

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, анимация, svg

Здравствуйте!

Есть `svg` `path` с координатами:

```
M 8,21 L 12,21 L 17,26 L 17,10 L 12,15 L 8,15 L 8,21 z M 19,14 L 19,22 C 20.48,21.32 21.5,19.77 21.5,18 C 21.5,16.26 20.48,14.74 19,14 z M 19,11.29 C 21.89,12.15 24,14.83 24,18 C 24,21.17 21.89,23.85 19,24.71 L 19,26.77 C 23.01,25.86 26,22.28 26,18 C 26,13.72 23.01,10.14 19,9.23 L 19,11.29 z
```

Как можно сделать, что бы координаты в `svg` `path` плавно изменились на эти при нажатии:

```
M 8,21 L 12,21 L 17,26 L 17,10 L 12,15 L 8,15 L 8,21 Z M 19,14 L 19,22 C 20.48,21.32 21.5,19.77 21.5,18 C 21.5,16.26 20.48,14.74 19,14 Z
```

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Решение с использованием анимаций SVG:

Для этого нам понадобится создать в path две анимации с нужными координатами и при нажатии на кнопку скриптом запускать одну из анимаций

Пример на сайте:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#button').click(function() {
    if ($('#button.-pause').length == 1 && $('#button.-play').length == 0) {
      $('#button svg path .button-play')[0].beginElement();
      $('#button').removeClass('-pause');
      $('#button').addClass('-play');
    } else {
      $('#button svg path  .button-pause')[0].beginElement();
      $('#button').removeClass('-play');
      $('#button').addClass('-pause');
    };
    return false;
  });
});
```

```css
@import url('data:text/css;charset=UTF-8,body { font-family: Tahoma, sans-serif; font-size: 0.8rem; } a {display: inline-block;color: #427fed;cursor: pointer;text-decoration: none;margin-right:5px;} a:hover {text-decoration: underline;} button { -webkit-padding-end: 10px; -webkit-padding-start: 10px; min-height: 2em; min-width: 4em; padding-bottom: 1px; -webkit-appearance: none; -webkit-user-select: none; background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#ededed, #ededed 38%, #dedede); border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25); border-radius: 2px; box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08), inset 0 1px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75); color: #444; font: inherit; margin: 0 1px 0 0; outline: none; text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgb(240, 240, 240); } button:hover { background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#f0f0f0, #f0f0f0 38%, #e0e0e0); border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3); box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), inset 0 1px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.95); color: black; } button:active { background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#e7e7e7, #e7e7e7 38%, #d7d7d7); box-shadow: none; text-shadow: none; } button:focus { -webkit-transition: border-color 200ms; border-color: rgb(77, 144, 254); outline: none; } select { -webkit-padding-end: 20px; -webkit-padding-start: 6px; background-position: right center; background-repeat: no-repeat; min-height: 2em; min-width: 4em; padding-bottom: 0; -webkit-user-select: none; background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#ededed, #ededed 38%, #dedede); border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25); border-radius: 2px; box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08), inset 0 1px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75); color: #444; font: inherit; margin: 0 1px 0 0; outline: none; text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgb(240, 240, 240); } select:hover { background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABMAAAAICAQAAACxSAwfAAAAUklEQ%E2%80%A6BbClcIUcSAw21QhXxfIIrwKAMpfNsEUYRXGVCEFc6CQwBqq4CCCtU4VgAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==), -webkit-linear-gradient(#f0f0f0, #f0f0f0 38%, #e0e0e0); border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3); box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), inset 0 1px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.95); color: black; } select:active { background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABMAAAAICAQAAACxSAwfAAAAUklEQ%E2%80%A6BbClcIUcSAw21QhXxfIIrwKAMpfNsEUYRXGVCEFc6CQwBqq4CCCtU4VgAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==), -webkit-linear-gradient(#e7e7e7, #e7e7e7 38%, #d7d7d7); box-shadow: none; text-shadow: none; } select:focus { -webkit-transition: border-color 200ms; border-color: rgb(77, 144, 254); outline: none; }');

#button {
  min-width: auto;
  padding: 3px 3px 0 1px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>

<button id="button" class="-pause">
  <svg width="36" height="36" viewBox="0 0 36 36">
    <path d="M 12,26 18.5,22 18.5,14 12,10 z M 18.5,22 25,18 25,18 18.5,14 z">
      <animate class="button-pause" attributeName="d" attributeType="XML" dur="0.15s" begin="none" fill="freeze" from="M 12,26 16,26 16,10 12,10 z M 21,26 25,26 25,10 21,10 z" to="M 12,26 18.5,22 18.5,14 12,10 z M 18.5,22 25,18 25,18 18.5,14 z" />
      <animate class="button-play" attributeName="d" attributeType="XML" dur="0.15s" begin="none" fill="freeze" from="M 12,26 18.5,22 18.5,14 12,10 z M 18.5,22 25,18 25,18 18.5,14 z" to="M 12,26 16,26 16,10 12,10 z M 21,26 25,26 25,10 21,10 z" />
    </path>
  </svg>
</button>
```

Answer (score 10):

### Решение данной проблемы с помощью JQuery:

```
$.prototype.animatePathD = function(d, o) {
  // Подстраиваем под разные браузера
  var i = $('body *').length;
  $('body').append('<svg id="animatepathd' + i + '" style="display:none"><path d="' + d + '"></svg>');
  d = $('#animatepathd' + i + ' path').attr('d');
  $('#animatepathd' + i).remove();

  var e = this,
    d = {
      primary: {
        frame: $(e).attr('d').replace(/\ \-[0-9.]+/g, ' {n}').replace(/[0-9.]+/g, '{n}'),
        coord: $(e).attr('d').replace(/[^0-9-.]+/g, ',').replace(/([0-9.]+)\-([0-9.]+)/g, '$1,$2').replace(/^\,(.+)\,$/, '$1').split(',')
      },
      final: {
        frame: d.replace(/\ \-[0-9.]+/g, ' {n}').replace(/[0-9.]+/g, '{n}'),
        coord: d.replace(/[^0-9-.]+/g, ',').replace(/([0-9.]+)\-([0-9.]+)/g, '$1,$2').replace(/^\,(.+)\,$/, '$1').split(',')
      }
    },
    opt = o;
  if (opt == undefined) {
    opt = {
      duration: 1000,
      easing: 'linear'
    };
  } else if (/^\d+$/.exec(opt) != null) {
    opt = {
      duration: opt,
      easing: 'linear'
    };
    if (opt.duration == undefined || /^\d+$/.exec(opt.duration) == null) {
      opt.duration = 1000
    };
  } else {
    if (opt.duration == undefined || /^\d+$/.exec(opt.duration) == null) {
      opt.duration = 1000
    };
    if (opt.easing != 'swing' && opt.easing != 'linear') {
      opt.easing = 'linear'
    };
  };
  if (d.primary.frame == d.final.frame) {
    var funPoint = {
      primary: {},
      final: {},
      list: '',
      frame: "'" + d.final.frame + "'"
    };
    for (var i = 0; i < d.primary.coord.length; i++) {
      funPoint.primary['c' + i] = d.primary.coord[i];
      funPoint.final['c' + i] = d.final.coord[i];
      funPoint.list = ', c' + i;
      if (d.primary.coord.length != 0) {
        funPoint.frame = funPoint.frame.replace(/\{n\}/, "'+obj.elem.c" + i + "+'")
      } else {
        funPoint.frame = funPoint.frame.replace(/\{n\}/, "'+c" + i + "+'")
      };
    };
    funPoint.list = funPoint.list.replace(/^\,\ (.+)$/, '$1');
    $(funPoint.primary).animate(funPoint.final, {
      duration: opt.duration,
      easing: opt.easing,
      step: function(c0, obj) {
        $(e).attr('d', eval(funPoint.frame));
      }
    });
  } else {
    console.error('Frameworks coordinates do not match!');
  };
};
```

Запускается он таким образом:
`$(svg path).animatePathD('coordinates', opt);`

**coordinates** - новые координаты;
**opt** - скорость выполнения анимации или параметры выполнения. Принимает всего 2 параметра: *duration (скорость выполнения; принимает только числа; по умолчанию - 1000)* и *easing (вид анимации; принимает два параметра: linear и swing; по умолчанию - linear)*;

*Пример на внешнем редакторе:* https://jsfiddle.net/yuri_spivak/ws4xknot/
*Пример на сайте:*

```js
$.prototype.animatePathD = function(d, o) {
  // Подстраиваем под разные браузера
  var i = $('body *').length;
  $('body').append('<svg id="animatepathd' + i + '" style="display:none"><path d="' + d + '"></svg>');
  d = $('#animatepathd' + i + ' path').attr('d');
  $('#animatepathd' + i).remove();

  var e = this,
    d = {
      primary: {
        frame: $(e).attr('d').replace(/\ \-[0-9.]+/g, ' {n}').replace(/[0-9.]+/g, '{n}'),
        coord: $(e).attr('d').replace(/[^0-9-.]+/g, ',').replace(/([0-9.]+)\-([0-9.]+)/g, '$1,$2').replace(/^\,(.+)\,$/, '$1').split(',')
      },
      final: {
        frame: d.replace(/\ \-[0-9.]+/g, ' {n}').replace(/[0-9.]+/g, '{n}'),
        coord: d.replace(/[^0-9-.]+/g, ',').replace(/([0-9.]+)\-([0-9.]+)/g, '$1,$2').replace(/^\,(.+)\,$/, '$1').split(',')
      }
    },
    opt = o;
  if (opt == undefined) {
    opt = {
      duration: 1000,
      easing: 'linear'
    };
  } else if (/^\d+$/.exec(opt) != null) {
    opt = {
      duration: opt,
      easing: 'linear'
    };
    if (opt.duration == undefined || /^\d+$/.exec(opt.duration) == null) {
      opt.duration = 1000
    };
  } else {
    if (opt.duration == undefined || /^\d+$/.exec(opt.duration) == null) {
      opt.duration = 1000
    };
    if (opt.easing != 'swing' && opt.easing != 'linear') {
      opt.easing = 'linear'
    };
  };
  if (d.primary.frame == d.final.frame) {
    var funPoint = {
      primary: {},
      final: {},
      list: '',
      frame: "'" + d.final.frame + "'"
    };
    for (var i = 0; i < d.primary.coord.length; i++) {
      funPoint.primary['c' + i] = d.primary.coord[i];
      funPoint.final['c' + i] = d.final.coord[i];
      funPoint.list = ', c' + i;
      if (d.primary.coord.length != 0) {
        funPoint.frame = funPoint.frame.replace(/\{n\}/, "'+obj.elem.c" + i + "+'")
      } else {
        funPoint.frame = funPoint.frame.replace(/\{n\}/, "'+c" + i + "+'")
      };
    };
    funPoint.list = funPoint.list.replace(/^\,\ (.+)$/, '$1');
    $(funPoint.primary).animate(funPoint.final, {
      duration: opt.duration,
      easing: opt.easing,
      step: function(c0, obj) {
        $(e).attr('d', eval(funPoint.frame));
      }
    });
  } else {
    console.error('Frameworks coordinates do not match!');
  };
};

$(function() {
  $('#button').click(function() {
    if ($('#button.-pause').length == 1 && $('#button.-play').length == 0) {
      $('#button svg path').animatePathD('M 12,26 16,26 16,10 12,10 z M 21,26 25,26 25,10 21,10 z', {
        duration: 150,
        easing: 'linear'
      });
      $('#button').removeClass('-pause');
      $('#button').addClass('-play');
    } else {
      $('#button svg path').animatePathD('M 12,26 18.5,22 18.5,14 12,10 z M 18.5,22 25,18 25,18 18.5,14 z', 150);
      $('#button').removeClass('-play');
      $('#button').addClass('-pause');
    };
    return false;
  });
});
```

```css
@import url('data:text/css;charset=UTF-8,body { font-family: Tahoma, sans-serif; font-size: 0.8rem; } a {display: inline-block;color: #427fed;cursor: pointer;text-decoration: none;margin-right:5px;} a:hover {text-decoration: underline;} button { -webkit-padding-end: 10px; -webkit-padding-start: 10px; min-height: 2em; min-width: 4em; padding-bottom: 1px; -webkit-appearance: none; -webkit-user-select: none; background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#ededed, #ededed 38%, #dedede); border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25); border-radius: 2px; box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08), inset 0 1px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75); color: #444; font: inherit; margin: 0 1px 0 0; outline: none; text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgb(240, 240, 240); } button:hover { background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#f0f0f0, #f0f0f0 38%, #e0e0e0); border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3); box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), inset 0 1px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.95); color: black; } button:active { background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#e7e7e7, #e7e7e7 38%, #d7d7d7); box-shadow: none; text-shadow: none; } button:focus { -webkit-transition: border-color 200ms; border-color: rgb(77, 144, 254); outline: none; } select { -webkit-padding-end: 20px; -webkit-padding-start: 6px; background-position: right center; background-repeat: no-repeat; min-height: 2em; min-width: 4em; padding-bottom: 0; -webkit-user-select: none; background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#ededed, #ededed 38%, #dedede); border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25); border-radius: 2px; box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08), inset 0 1px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75); color: #444; font: inherit; margin: 0 1px 0 0; outline: none; text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgb(240, 240, 240); } select:hover { background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABMAAAAICAQAAACxSAwfAAAAUklEQ%E2%80%A6BbClcIUcSAw21QhXxfIIrwKAMpfNsEUYRXGVCEFc6CQwBqq4CCCtU4VgAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==), -webkit-linear-gradient(#f0f0f0, #f0f0f0 38%, #e0e0e0); border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3); box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), inset 0 1px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.95); color: black; } select:active { background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABMAAAAICAQAAACxSAwfAAAAUklEQ%E2%80%A6BbClcIUcSAw21QhXxfIIrwKAMpfNsEUYRXGVCEFc6CQwBqq4CCCtU4VgAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==), -webkit-linear-gradient(#e7e7e7, #e7e7e7 38%, #d7d7d7); box-shadow: none; text-shadow: none; } select:focus { -webkit-transition: border-color 200ms; border-color: rgb(77, 144, 254); outline: none; }');

#button {
  min-width: auto;
  padding: 3px 3px 0 1px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>

<button id="button" class="-pause">
  <svg width="36" height="36" viewBox="0 0 36 36">
    <path d="M 12,26 18.5,22 18.5,14 12,10 z M 18.5,22 25,18 25,18 18.5,14 z"></path>
  </svg>
</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

### Вариант скрипта с использованием стандартной анимации `svg`:

```
$.prototype.animatePathD = function(d) {
  var e = this,
      animate = $(e).find('animate[data-animatePathD]');
  if(animate.length){
    animate.attr({
      'attributeName': 'd', 
      'attributeType': 'XML',
      'from': animate.attr('to') || $(e).attr('d'),
      'to': d,
      'fill': 'freeze'
    });
    animate[0].beginElement();
  };
};
```

**Запуск:**

1. Добавляем в `path` элемент `animate` с атрибутом **`data-animatePathD`** и всеми нужными свойствами

> *Пример:*
>
> ```
> <path>
>   <animate data-animatePathD dur="0.15s" begin="none" />
> </path>
> ```

2. В функции JS меняем координаты функцией: `$(svg path).animatePathD('coordinates');`

**svg path** - путь к элементу path;
**coordinates** - новые координаты;

*Пример на сайте:*

```js
$.prototype.animatePathD = function(d) {
  var e = this,
      animate = $(e).find('animate[data-animatePathD]');
  if(animate.length){
    animate.attr({
      'attributeName': 'd', 
      'attributeType': 'XML',
      'from': animate.attr('to') || $(e).attr('d'),
      'to': d,
      'fill': 'freeze'
    });
    animate[0].beginElement();
  };
};

$(function() {
  $('#button').click(function() {
    if ($('#button.-pause').length == 1 && $('#button.-play').length == 0) {
      $('#button svg path').animatePathD('M 12,26 16,26 16,10 12,10 z M 21,26 25,26 25,10 21,10 z');
      $('#button').removeClass('-pause');
      $('#button').addClass('-play');
    } else {
      $('#button svg path').animatePathD('M 12,26 18.5,22 18.5,14 12,10 z M 18.5,22 25,18 25,18 18.5,14 z');
      $('#button').removeClass('-play');
      $('#button').addClass('-pause');
    };
    return false;
  });
});
```

```css
@import url('data:text/css;charset=UTF-8,body { font-family: Tahoma, sans-serif; font-size: 0.8rem; } a {display: inline-block;color: #427fed;cursor: pointer;text-decoration: none;margin-right:5px;} a:hover {text-decoration: underline;} button { -webkit-padding-end: 10px; -webkit-padding-start: 10px; min-height: 2em; min-width: 4em; padding-bottom: 1px; -webkit-appearance: none; -webkit-user-select: none; background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#ededed, #ededed 38%, #dedede); border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25); border-radius: 2px; box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08), inset 0 1px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75); color: #444; font: inherit; margin: 0 1px 0 0; outline: none; text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgb(240, 240, 240); } button:hover { background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#f0f0f0, #f0f0f0 38%, #e0e0e0); border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3); box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), inset 0 1px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.95); color: black; } button:active { background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#e7e7e7, #e7e7e7 38%, #d7d7d7); box-shadow: none; text-shadow: none; } button:focus { -webkit-transition: border-color 200ms; border-color: rgb(77, 144, 254); outline: none; } select { -webkit-padding-end: 20px; -webkit-padding-start: 6px; background-position: right center; background-repeat: no-repeat; min-height: 2em; min-width: 4em; padding-bottom: 0; -webkit-user-select: none; background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#ededed, #ededed 38%, #dedede); border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25); border-radius: 2px; box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08), inset 0 1px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75); color: #444; font: inherit; margin: 0 1px 0 0; outline: none; text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgb(240, 240, 240); } select:hover { background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABMAAAAICAQAAACxSAwfAAAAUklEQ%E2%80%A6BbClcIUcSAw21QhXxfIIrwKAMpfNsEUYRXGVCEFc6CQwBqq4CCCtU4VgAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==), -webkit-linear-gradient(#f0f0f0, #f0f0f0 38%, #e0e0e0); border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3); box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), inset 0 1px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.95); color: black; } select:active { background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABMAAAAICAQAAACxSAwfAAAAUklEQ%E2%80%A6BbClcIUcSAw21QhXxfIIrwKAMpfNsEUYRXGVCEFc6CQwBqq4CCCtU4VgAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==), -webkit-linear-gradient(#e7e7e7, #e7e7e7 38%, #d7d7d7); box-shadow: none; text-shadow: none; } select:focus { -webkit-transition: border-color 200ms; border-color: rgb(77, 144, 254); outline: none; }');

#button {
  min-width: auto;
  padding: 3px 3px 0 1px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>

<button id="button" class="-pause">
  <svg width="36" height="36" viewBox="0 0 36 36">
    <path d="M 12,26 18.5,22 18.5,14 12,10 z M 18.5,22 25,18 25,18 18.5,14 z">
      <animate data-animatePathD dur="0.15s" begin="none" />
    </path>
  </svg>
</button>
```